# Updated Value in SQL Server specially in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

How can detect an updated value in a Trigger specially in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer true !!
An UPDATE trigger is used to perform an action after an update is made on a table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Orders_UPDATE
ON Orders
AFTER UPDATE
AS

--Make sure Priority was changed
IF NOT UPDATE(Ord_Priority)
RETURN

--Determine if Priority was changed to high
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
       FROM INSERTED a
   JOIN DELETED b ON a.Ord_ID=b.Ord_ID
   WHERE b.Ord_Priority <> 'High' AND
   a.Ord_Priority = 'High')
BEGIN
DECLARE @Count tinyint
SET @Count = (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM INSERTED a
    JOIN DELETED b ON a.Ord_ID=b.Ord_ID
    WHERE b.Ord_Priority <> 'High' AND
    a.Ord_Priority = 'High')
PRINT CAST(@Count as varchar(3))+' row(s) where changed to a priority of High'
END
go
```

In Part I the INSERT trigger watched for orders with a priority of 'High.' The UPDATE trigger watches for orders whose priority are changed from something else to High.

The IF statement checks to see if the Ord_Priority value was changed. If not we can save some time by exiting the trigger immediately.

The deleted table holds the pre-UPDATE values and inserted table holds the new values. When the tables are joined it is easy to tell when the priority changes from something else to High.

[Reference](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-ii)

Answer (score 1):

```
IF UPDATE (mycol1)
```

e.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER reminder
ON Person.Address
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
IF ( UPDATE (StateProvinceID) OR UPDATE (PostalCode) )
BEGIN
    RAISERROR (50009, 16, 10)
END;
GO
```

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx).

If you are refering to the actual values, these are held in the `inserted` and `deleted` tables. See [Using the inserted and deleted Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

Comment: this sample code detects if these columns has been changed or not ! and doesn't get us the changed and updated value

Comment: the changed and updated values are in the inserted and deleted pseudo tables available to triggers (depends on trigger type).

Answer (score 1):

Note that you shouldn't try to get the value because triggers should be coded to deal with multiple row changes

That said, you can use the special DELETED and INSERTED tables

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_SomeTable_U ON dbo.SomeTable AFTER UPDATE 
AS 

-- DECLARE @ TABLE ...
-- INSERT HistoryTable
-- whatever

SELECT
    ...
FROM
   INSERTED I
   JOIN
   UPDATED U ON I.PK 0 U.PK
WHERE
  I.SomeColumn <> U.SomeColumn -- does not handle NULLs
GO
```